# See what bitrate/frequency MacOS is sending to DAC

Tags: macos, audio

I've recently revised my audio setup, and while I have it set to send 24-bit/192khz, I'm curious if there's a way to see what the audio going out actually "hits." I'm using Amazon Music HD, with several albums that are in "Ultra HD" which tops out at 24/192 I believe. But curious what's actually going to my DAC. Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: If you've got it set that high, then what's going out is 'what the file playing is encoded at', assuming the playback app is also capable [which most are these days].

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. Is the application actually sending 24/192?

Like I know some lower resolution tracks are sent at 44.1khz and I'd be very interested to see when that's the case.

Comment: Can't help, sorry. I've been a professional sound engineer for 35 years & never been bothered enough to care ;) I know what's going on in my DAW & that suits me, random 'interweb' playback just plays at whatever it is. I doubt you'll be able to tell the difference really. Don't let it worry you ;)) I just looked up their spec & it's still compressed audio anyway; I'm gonna call it 'marketing ploy'. Very few people have speakers capable of showing the difference .

Comment: Haha thanks anyways man. I thought Amazon was lossless? Do you have a link? I have a miniDSP DDRC-24 and SHD, and HEDD type 07 and type 20 Mk2's so even if I can't tell the difference really I like to get the best that I can :)

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/music/unlimited/why-hd?ref=dmm_LP_WHYHD See https://www.colincrawley.com/audio-file-size-calculator/ for a calculator. I dialled in a 'per second' figure for 24-bit 192kHz, compressed & uncompressed, using 'real' wav data vs Amazon's highest claimed streaming bit-rate - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qpfh.png

Comment: Super interesting. I wonder if it's just in FLAC or if they're lying and using a lossy compression format for the 24/192 tracks. Oddly that's why I left Tidal, was sick of all the MQA stuff where you need a DAC that can "unfold" it enough times.

Comment: Ah, I just saw your added speaker info. idk the HEDDs personally - but you have to bear in mind most people when asked have earbuds, not studio monitors, hence my initial skepticism;)) Yeah, you'll be able to hear the difference between 'cheap' mp3s & 'good' ones on those. Whether you'll really spot the difference between 24-bit 44.1kHz wav & streamed 24-bit 192kHz… I honestly don't know. [btw, I used to use Genelc 32-2Bs but I never found them to be capable of portable mixes. I switched to the dynAudio BM6As when they were the 'big new thing' & love them.]

Comment: Tidal & Spotify say they can stream flac. tbh, streaming is not my forté so idk for sure who's using what these days.

Comment: Of course, right now, I'm listening to Boris Johnson streaming in… ooohh, maybe 32kbps [on the dynaudios]  ;)))

Comment: Oh man that sounds like a great setup! And yea, I've been into this stuff my whole life. Just replaced my B&Ws with the HEDDs. I also have a set of JH Audio in ears for when I'm traveling. I wasn't aware Spotify is using FLAC now, I just know they announced a high resolution service coming later this year which is awesome. I do have a collection of FLAC vinyl rips, but streaming services have actually gotten so much better quality wise, it's almost pointless.Thanks again for the info!

Comment: FLAC is unlikely able to achieve such a compression ratio (9216:3730=2.47:1). Unless it's using some even better lossless codec, it's probably some lossy files encoded from hi-res master. (1411:850=1.66:1 is more achievable, so maybe lossless red book but lossy hi-res...) I wonder if CoreAudio provides something like `pacmd list-sink-inputs` in PulseAudio btw...(that only tells what the player app is emitting though; the app could still be up/downsampling and truncating/zero-padding/interpolating/dithering, and those have nothing to do whether the stream is lossy or lossless...).

Comment: Besides, what your DAC receives ultimately depends on what CoreAudio emits...which could heavily depends on your settings...

Comment: Hmm, ["average"](https://www.amazon.com/b?ie=UTF8&node=14070322011): `Ultra HD tracks have a bit depth of 24 bits, with sample rates ranging from 44.1 kHz up to 192 kHz, and an average bitrate of 3730 kbps.`

Comment: `Below are examples of file sizes for a 3½ minute song / Ultra HD (lossless, max 192 kHz sample rate): 153 MB`: 9216:(153 * 1000 * 8 / (60 * 3.5)) = 1.58:1

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I dealt with this; I wanted to get my DAC's current playing bitrate as Tidal now supports hi-res FLAC.

1. Find your DAC!

```
system_profiler SPAudioDataType
```

- this will give you all your audio devices. In my case, this was "iFi (by AMR) HD USB Audio"

2. Get the DAC's info:

```
system_profiler SPAudioDataType | grep -A 7 "iFi (by AMR) HD USB Audio"

Output: 
iFi (by AMR) HD USB Audio :

          Manufacturer: iFi (by AMR)
          Output Channels: 2
          Current SampleRate: 96000
          Transport: USB
          Output Source: Default
```

3. Get just the bitrate

```
system_profiler SPAudioDataType | grep -A 7 "iFi (by AMR) HD USB Audio" | grep "Current SampleRate"

Output:
Current SampleRate: 96000
```

4. Format the message all nice:

```
system_profiler SPAudioDataType | grep -A 7 "iFi (by AMR) HD USB Audio" | grep "Current SampleRate" | sed 's/Current SampleRate:/DAC (kHz):/g'

Output:
DAC (kHz): 96000
```

5. Download and install `xbar` https://github.com/matryer/xbar
6. Add the following bash script to the `xbar` plugins folder
   filename: `ifi-bitrate.2s.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
system_profiler SPAudioDataType | grep -A 7 "iFi (by AMR) HD USB Audio" | grep "Current SampleRate" | sed 's/Current SampleRate:/DAC (kHz):/g'
```

7. Ensure you chmod the plugin file after creation:

```
chmod +x ifi-bitrate.2s.sh
```

8. Run xbar and you should see the following in your MacOS taskbar

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec6bv.png